# why OS processes seems faster than threads in java

Tags: java, concurrency, operating-system

I developed a multi-thread java application which using thread to process a batch of work. I have a main thread which dispatching the works to different threads. All work fine.

Now I have changed the application to allow it to run in multiple java process, each doing multi-thread processing as before. For example, I use to have 8 threads to process 8 jobs in one java process, now I can have 2 Java processes with each have 4 threads still to process 8 jobs in total.

The application is modeled like this: a dispatcher will fetch the work need to be done, then dispatch them to a thread pool. There is no synchronization or communication between the threads.

I have notice quite a big performance gain in the later approach and I'm wondering why. Can anyone shed some insight on this? Is the OS process scheduling much more efficient that java threads? Should I use this as a general rule of thumb when I really need that performance gain? thanks.

Comment: This question is pretty much impossible to answer without your code (synchronization and communication between threads has overhead), even ignoring the relation threads have to processes in terms of scheduling priority is going to differ from platform to platform.

Comment: Have you tested the performance (throughtput) with only one 4 thread process compared to two processes? Or two processes with 8 threads or 2 threads?

How many cores? What kind of processing is being done and how?

Comment: Most likely you have a resource bottleneck which you have doubled by having two processes.  In generally you save overhead by having one process when it is well tuned.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on lots of factors. Firstly have you looked at the CPU and memory load levels in both cases? I expect that in the two processes case the system is in a greater load hence working faster.

Another reason for this might be the fact that you simply have two distinct memory heaps which are cleaned by two separately garbage collectors.

Also how do the processes communicate with each other (file, pipe, queue, socket etc.)? In multiple processes case you cannot share memory (unless you call some OS system calls which comes at a cost). Have you taken this communication time into consideration when measuring the time?

Comment: Sounds good. Two JVMs with same settings equals twice as much memory. There is much more memory available for doing the processing. It might avoid full gc altogether. Many times using less threads seems to slow things down not to speed them up.

Garbage collecting might not be speeding factor because there is probably twice the memory for doing the collecting. Also JIT has to be done twice for each process.

Comment: this sounds reasonable. the application is not CPU intensive but do require lots of memories.